# Migrating database causes CodeIgniter error '...undefined method: CI_DB_mysqli_driver::first_row()'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

A fully functional CodeIgniter application has had it's MySQL database migrated from server A to server B.

Ever since the migration, the following code throws an error:

```
$part = $this->db->select('')
    ->where('id', $part_id)
    ->limit(1)
    ->get('part')
    ->first_row('array');
```

The exact PHP **error**:

> Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::first_row()

As per the documentation, first_row('array') most definitely is a valid method: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-rows

Also, this application has worked in production for months, so the error is explicitly linked to migrating the database.

**The question**
What could have been misconfigured on the new database server that causes this error?

**Note 1:** After migrating the database, for some reason all table and column names that were previously camel cased (documentId e.g.), were somehow cast to lower case.

**Note 2:** Using query results as arrays, which is very common in CodeIgniter, throws an error such as `Message: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysqli_driver as array`.

Comment: i'm not sure ... this looks like you migrated an old CI Version or something like that, because if you take a look @ https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_result.php#L456 you can see this function exists - check your codeigniter.php in the system directory and take a look @your defined `CI_VERSION` constant; you should check your DB_result.php in system/database too

Comment: I am using CI_VERSION 3.1.3. Also note that _nothing_ has changed to the source code, only the database was migrated. As you said, in `DB_result.php`, the method exists. So it seems that my database is not returning a DB_result, rather, it is returning a CI_DB_mysqli_driver class (whatever that may be).

Comment: It is NOT possible that this is caused by a database migration. Double and triple check this; the message says that `CI_DB_driver::get()` returns an instance of itself, which is not true.